# Conceptual understanding of waiting time problem involving exponential distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am working on a textbook problem that says,

> A doorman at a hotel is trying to get three taxicabs for three different couples. The arrival of empty cabs has an exponential distribution with mean 2 minutes. Assuming independence, what is the probability that the doorman will get all three couples taken care of within 6 minutes?

(Robert V. Hogg et al., *Probability and Statistical Inference* 9e, exercise 5.4.19.)

I can see two ways of approaching this problem:

Each taxi's arrival time has the cdf $F(x) = 1-e^{-x/2}$. Then the probability of one given taxi arriving in 6 minutes is $1- e^{-6/2}$, and the probability of this happening three times is $\left(1- e^{-3}\right)^3 = 0.8580$ **(answer 1)**.  This is equivalent to defining $Y = \max(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ and finding $P(Y \leq 6)$.

But we could also say that $f(x)$ is counting the time until the "next" taxi. Then we define $X_1 + X_2 + X_3 = Z$, the total time until three taxis have shown up. Since each $X_i$ has the mgf $M_X(t) = (1-2t)^{-1}$,

$$M_Z(t) = \prod_{i=0}^3 M_{X_i} = (1-2t)^{-3}$$

This is gamma with $\alpha = 3$ and $\theta = 2$. Using Python, I get this **(answer 2)**:

```
In [265]: from scipy.stats import gamma
In [266]: gamma.cdf(6, 3, 2)
Out[266]: 0.7618966944464556
```

The solutions page says, without explanation, that the answer is $ 1 −( 17/2 )e^3 = 0.5768$ [sic: should have $e^{-3}$] **(answer 3)**.

What are the assumptions behind these three different approaches? Where did the textbook's answer come from? Which approach is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us address the textbook's solution and its origin.  This solution relies on observing that the taxicab arrivals constitute a **Poisson process** with intensity $\lambda = 1/2$ taxis per minute.  Consequently, we seek the probability that by time $t = 6$ minutes, we have observed at least $3$ taxis.  The counting random variable for the number of taxis observed by time $t$ is $$X_t \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda t),$$ with $$\Pr[X_t = x] = e^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^x}{x!}, \quad x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots.$$  Consequently $$\Pr[X_6 \ge 3] = 1 - \Pr[X_6 \le 2] = 1 - e^{-3} \frac{3^0}{0!} - e^{-3} \frac{3^1}{1!} - e^{-3} \frac{3^2}{2!} = 1 - \frac{17}{2}e^{-3},$$ as claimed.

Now we turn our attention to the first solution you describe.  The flaw is one of interpretation.  The arrival of taxicabs is a serial process, not a parallel one; thus, the statement that the time of arrival of empty cabs is exponentially distributed means that these are **interarrival** times, not absolute times.  In other words, conditioned on the random arrival of a cab, the arrival time of the next cab is exponential with mean $2$ minutes.  The model used in the first solution's calculation might apply to a scenario where, for instance, three cabs are known to be arriving independently of each other, each one's arrival time is exponential with mean $2$ minutes, and you want to know the probability that the last cab to arrive will do so within $6$ minutes.  But this is not how the question is set up.  In particular, this solution fails to model situations where four cabs, or even ten cabs, might show up in $6$ minutes.

For the second solution, the method is correct, and you should have gotten the same numeric result as with the third (textbook) solution.  The time-to-event random variable $T_x$ that measures the time it takes to observe the $x^{\rm th}$ arrival is gamma with shape $x$ and intensity (rate) $\lambda = 1/2$, i.e. $$T_3 \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(3, \lambda = 1/2), \quad f_{T_x}(t) = \frac{\lambda^x t^{x-1} e^{-\lambda t}}{\Gamma(x)}, \\
\Pr[T_3 \le 6] = \int_{t=0}^6 \frac{t^2 e^{-t/2}}{16} \, dt.$$  I suspect you obtained the result you did because you specified the arguments incorrectly; however, I am not familiar with Python.  I believe you must type instead

```
gamma.cdf(6, 3, scale=2)
```

because otherwise Python will interpret the third argument as a **location** parameter, and leave the scale parameter at the default value of $1$.  So your syntax is actually equivalent to

```
gamma.cdf(6, 3, loc=2, scale=1)
```

which in turn is also equivalent to

```
gamma.cdf(4, 3)
```

Comment: You are very good at Python for someone who is "not familiar with Python." Thanks!